# getting include error on external libraries C++ code in Visual Studio on mac os

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am new to c++ programming. coding in visual studio code. I have downloaded PCL library and Eigen library from Homebrew on mac os. both installed successfully. But when I include it library my current script, I always get no such file. Thank you.`test.cpp`:

```
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
```

also edited `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
"includePath": 
["${workspaceFolder}/**",
 "/usr/local/Cellar/pcl/1.9.1_9/include/pcl-1.9/**"],
```

and edited `tasks.json`

```
"args": 
["-g","${file}","-o","${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
"-I", "/usr/local/Cellar/pcl/1.9.1_9/include/pcl-1.9/**"],
```

any suggestions for good debugging code editor also helpful. currently using visual studio code for debugging.

Comment: Have verified that file `/usr/local/Cellar/pcl/1.9.1_9/include/pcl-1.9/pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h` actuallu exists? I have a hunch that the path is wrong.

Comment: yes I have verified it. it was there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://https:/stackoverflow.com/questions/9755261/c-include-libraries "C++ include libraries" post by the user "nos" which I believe should solve your issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This answer seems to be more a comment, so when you'll reach enough reputation to comment (`50 rep`), it's recommended to use that function

Comment: Thanks for you answer. but that is related to linux os and also it is not with vscode. I am having problem with vscode debugging.